# Java Loading XML Unknown Class Type

Tags: java, xml, libgdx

I'm currently working on a Mario-esque platformer in Java in my spare time as a means of trying concepts that I don't have experience in. One of these is the loading and storing of information in XML files so that the game could in theory be modified by the end user or by an editing tool without the need to have the source code/recompile the game.

I've been fairly successful on my own thus far but I'm at a point where I'm completely unsure how to progress. I'm trying to load the entities that will be found on a level from an XML file. The XML file currently contains other information such as the map location and the player spawn point which works correctly using the w3c Document Object Model.

My difficulty comes from the fact that I need to load multiple types of entities (special blocks, monsters, etc.) from the file and I'd really prefer not to have to hard code in each time in my loader method so that when a new class is added, for example Monster3.java, I could simply add a few lines to my XML file and the Monster3s would be created without editing the loader method.

Here is the current format of my level file:

```
<level>
    <map>data\level2.tmx</map>

    <player file="data\player.xml">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>48</y>
    </player>

    <entities>
        <entity type="monster1" file="data\monster1.xml">
            <x>48</x>
            <y>48</y>
        </entity>

        <entity type="monster1" file="data\monster.xml">
            <x>96</x>
            <y>48</y>
        </entity>    
    </entities>
</level>
```

Just for some background information, all of the monsters extend a central Entity class. All of them have their own constructor to setup specifics for that type of monster that calls a super with the same provided parameters (a string representing the location of the file and a Vector2 with the starting position). I do not expect to be handed code, I'd simply like to be pushed in the correct direction.

Comment: `Monster1`, `Monster2`, `Monster3`, etc. are all different CLASSES?  Why?

Comment: I don't intend to have the same behavior for every Entity. The Entity class is used for anything dynamic, such as a coin or a special block.

Comment: I understand that a `Coin` class and a `Monster` class may be necessary.  What I don't understand is why every `Monster` needs its own class and why they can't all use the same `Monster` class.

Comment: They're different types of Monsters, I'm not using a different class for every single instance but each type has behavior specific to it. For example, Monster1 may just roam randomly whereas Monster2 may specifically seek the player. (These are all just hypothetical and simplified examples.)

Comment: @nhgrif `Bird` monsters and `Kitty` monsters are inherently different monsters, and not just by name. You can have a generic `Monster` class with child classes `Bird` and `Kitty` but then I'd probably still store them as `Bird` and `Kitty` objects.

Comment: Okay, so even if you have a handful of different `Monster` classes, you shouldn't have an unlimited amount of `Monster` classes, should you?  Hmm, wait... okay I'm starting to see the issue now... hang on...

Comment: If you already use the type information as monster1 why not use this info to create a monster1 object or whatever class you like?

Comment: That's essentially what I'm attempting to do. I currently have the Level file being loaded and I can grab the Entity node and process each Entity in it but I don't know how to create an instance of that specific class based solely on the the text in type. I could do it fairly easily by just putting a switch in based on the type but I'd prefer to not have to go back and edit the Level loader each time a new subclass of Entity is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for here is **'Reflection'**.

```
//Fully qualified name
String typeName = "com.yourcompany.product.Monster3";

try {
    //Class from name
    Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(typeName);

    //Constructor from Parameter types...
    Class<?>[] types = {Double.TYPE, String.class};
    Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor(types);

    //Instance from Parameter values...
    Object[] parameters = {new Double(0), "Hello"};
    Object instanceOfMyClass = constructor.newInstance(parameters);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note**:
An important issue here is type-safety.
When your software becomes large, it would be increasingly difficult to debug.
So I would suggest the usage of *Abstract Factory* pattern which seems appropriate to me for your use case.
Also, it's wise to spend time on implementing a type-safe abstract factory (using of-course generics) to make life easier afterwards.

Hope this helps